# Why does my unit test fail to return the text within a single-file component where I set that text with $el.innerText on the mounted hook?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-test-utils

**Summary of Problem**

I have content-editable `div` that receives a `content` property whose default value is an empty string. **Instead** of using mustache syntax to render the property `{{ content }}`, I set the elements innerText via the mounted hook:

`mounted() {this.$el.innerText = this.content}`

I've created a unit test to verify the text of the component contains the mocked property I passed into the test.

The component renders properly in the browser, but the unit test fails, alerting me that it didn't find any text.

**Things I've tried**

If I log `wrapper.vm.$el.innerText` I see the string I mock.

If I use mustache syntax (and not the mounted method) i.e `<div>}{{ content}}</div>`, the test passes.

**Vue single-file component**

```
<template>
  <div
    contenteditable="true"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      content: {
        default: '',
        type: String,
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$el.innerText = this.content;
    },
  }
</script>
```

**Unit test**

```
describe('BaseEditable.vue', () => {
  it('renders content property', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(BaseEditable, {
      propsData: {
        content: 'some random string',
      },
    });
    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('some random string');
});
```

**What I expect, and what I got**

I expect the test to pass.

However, the result I receive is:

```
expect(string).toContain(value)

Expected string:
  ""

To contain value:
  "some random string"
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why this happens, but I was able to reproduce your error and "fix" it by using

```
  this.$el.innerHTML = this.content;
```

instead of

```
  this.$el.innerText = this.content;
```

EDIT:

I'm not completely sure of this, but `vue-test-utils` uses `jest` with [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) by [default](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/choosing-a-test-runner.html), and according to [this](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1245) issue, they haven't implemented `innerText` yet.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Still curious about innerText not working. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah I was curious too, it looks like a problem with jsdom.  You could probably fix it by configuring another test runner which uses something else.  `vue-webpack` used to use (current uses?) `nightwatch` which ran chromium.